# Bizarre FontAwesome input placeholder bug

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome to include an icon in the placeholder of an input.

Here's my code:

`<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="&#xf023; &nbsp;  Password">`

But the view on the screen is displayed as "Passw rd".

When I change the placeholder value to `&#xf023; &nbsp;  Passward`, or any other letter other than "o", than it displays perfectly fine.  What's up?

**Update:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    src:url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('eot'),
    url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome) format('svg');
    font-weight:400;font-style:normal;
}
```

Including this code aboves causes o's to not appear.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/9HkRt/

Comment: Wow, entity codes works with FontAwesome? cool.

Comment: In which browser do you have that problem?

Comment: can you create fiddle ?

Comment: I tested this [jsfddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKck6/)  in chrome and it works without any problems.

Comment: In the JSFiddle I posted above, at least on my computer, that is not the case.

Comment: Hahaha sorry, one sec.

Comment: Looks like a bug with version 2 of FontAwesome. Is there a reason why you don't use version 4?

Comment: AWESOME-- thanks a ton.  It is a bug with version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**t.niese** in the comments solved it-- it's simply a bug with version 2 of FontAwesome.

Comment: I did some additional research, on the one hand there was an empty entry in the _v2_ for the letter `o` and because of that the `o` was invisible. On the other hand the comments in the Issue _[Missing Lowercase letter `o` on paragraph](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/417)_ say that you should not mix regular text with icons in the same tag. You should do some further research yourself to find if it still could be a problem, e.g. with other browsers or for some other situations.